# Confusion on Locally Integrable Function Induced Measure is Regular

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, proof-explanation, quantifiers

The statement that I am trying the proof of is:

> $f \,dm$ is regular iff $f \in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n, m)$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Here is the proof provided by Folland:[image]

**In the proof, Folland utilized Corollary 3.6:** [image]

However, $f$ is required in Corollary 3.6 to be **integrable** instead of only **locally integrable**. **So why is it appropriate to use the corollary here?**

One argument that I have seen is that as both $U$ and $E$ are bounded, they are both contained in some compact sets $K$, and thus we can just apply the corollary to $f\chi_K$. However, I am not very convinced by this argument as in my mind, $K$ has to be independent of the choice of $\delta$ here to use corollary for the following reason: Given $\epsilon > 0$, in order for us to determine which $\delta > 0$ to use, we need to invoke corollary 3.6 already. But how do we invoke corollary 3.6 without knowing $U$, which is based on the choice of $\delta > 0$? Maybe I am just confused about the quantifier here, but it seems like then the logic is circular here.

**Definition of Regular Borel Measures**:
[image]